# What is a good math joke?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, big-list

Do you guys know any good math jokes? Thanks 3000. I would like to know a couple math jokes to use on my math teacher.

Comment: what do you call a grape that commutes?  an Abelian grape

Comment: Why is $\pi$ sad? ‘Cos $\pi$ is negative.

Comment: I have a math joke but I'm $2^2$ to say it.

Comment: I know some, but not appropriate for your math teacher, for example: you'll get a tenure track position.

Comment: What do you get when you cross a mosquito with a mountain climber? Nothing, you can't cross a vector with a scalar.

Comment: I know I should vote to close this but I'm totally ok with this being a quesion (as long as it is CW)

Comment: From Munkres topology: "How is a set different from a door? A door must be either open or closed, and cannot be both, while a set can be open, or closed, or both, or neither!"

Comment: [MathOverflow has a chatroom for jokes.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92902/jokes)

Comment: There was once a thread on MO for the sole purpose of collecting *good* math jokes, but [apparently it good deleted recently](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4328/why-was-the-whole-math-jokes-thread-deleted-and-should-it-have-been).

Comment: An extremely elaborate one but still the best I've seen so far [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/929r9g/an_infinite_number_of_mathematicians_walk_into_a/)

Comment: This is a favorite.  Perhaps too long, though.  https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/08/21/five-math-experts-split-the-check/

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/xXuJLDF) has to be my favorite one of all time. PG-13 alert.

Comment: What's yellow and equivalent to the axiom of choice? Zorn's lemon.